# PowerMockRunner does not apply JUnit ClassRules

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I need to mock a static method of a class and use that mocked method in my test. Right now seems I can only use PowerMock to do that.

I annotate the class with @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class), and @PrepareForTest with the appropriate class.

In my test I have a @ClassRule, but when running the tests, the rule is not applied properly.

What can i do ?

```
    RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({
    "javax.xml.*",
    "org.xml.*",
    "org.w3c.*",
    "javax.management.*"
})
@PrepareForTest(Request.class)
public class RoleTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static HibernateSessionRule sessionRule = new HibernateSessionRule(); // this Rule doesnt applied
```

Comment: Just for tracing: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/687 . PowerMock basically breaks JUnit test handling, and there is no real plan to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into the PowerMock code. It looks like `PowerMockRunner` does not support `@ClassRule`. You can try to use the `HibernateSessionRule` as a `@Rule` instead of a `@ClassRule`.

```
@PrepareForTest(Request.class)
public class RoleTest {

  @Rule
  public HibernateSessionRule sessionRule = new HibernateSessionRule();
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way of working around this problem is to use the `org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate` annotation:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({
    "javax.xml.*",
    "org.xml.*",
    "org.w3c.*",
    "javax.management.*"
})
@PrepareForTest(Request.class)
public class RoleTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static HibernateSessionRule sessionRule = new HibernateSessionRule(); // this Rule now applied
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution only valid with PowerMock 1.4 or major. I added these dependencies to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-classloading-xstream</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and changed my code removing `@RunWith` annotation and using a simple JUnit `@Rule`

```
@PrepareForTest(X.class);
public class MyTest {
    @Rule
    PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    // Tests goes here
    ...
}
```

for more information visit PowerMock's [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/powermockrule)